# Blow up singularities on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, resolution-of-singularities, blow-ups

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\bar{\mathbb F}_p$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$. Let $C$ be an irreducible singular projective curve over $\bar{\mathbb F}_p$.

Let $P$ be a singularity on $C$, suppose that we get $N(P)$ points after blowing up $P$. If $N(P) = 2$, then do we know which type of singularities $P$ could be?

Comment: By "blowing up" do you mean a single blowup of the maximal ideal of $P$ or do you mean whatever series of blowups it takes to make $P$ smooth? And in the first case, do you assume the blowup of $C$ is smooth?

Comment: Thanks for your question, I mean whatever series of blowups it takes to make  smooth.

Comment: $C$ will have two local irreducible components at $P$. For example the vanishing locus of $x^a- y^b$ has this form whenever $\gcd(a,b)=2\neq p$.